# Laravel: routing multiple websites to one Laravel app folder in shared hosting, different routes

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, shared-hosting

I have no idea how to do this, and I have to use this hosting option.

I have a `public_html` dir in my home, this folder has a website in it already.

Then inside the `public_html` there is a symlink to my laravel folder, let's call it `laravel`. So whenever I go to `myhost.com/laravel` it works, I get the laravel app. The route inside the app for this is `/`.

What I would like to do now is make another symlink in `public_html`, point it to the same laravel app, but use a different route. So for example, I create a symlink `app2` to the laravel folder but hit a different route than `/`.

Is this possible? I have no sudo access, no vhosts configuration.

I'm guessing it could be possible with `.htaccess` rewriting sorcery, but I have no knowledge on where to even start.

Thank you.

Comment: -2 and not a single comment, could you at least explain what's wrong with the question? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `myhost.com/app2`? This is supposed to work fine.

Comment: It doesn't, since it points to the public folder, it just grabs the `/` route.

Comment: Ok, is that I have something similar, and if the dir exists the route is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so besides being downvoted without criticism, I solved my problem. Here is how:

I had to add a prefix to my urls, so `a.com/x` became `a.com/apps/x`.

Added a symlink to the laravel `public` folder in the `public_html` called apps. Then added routes `x` and `y` to laravel.

Created folders `x` and `y` inside `public_html` and, inside these folders, made a always redirect `.htaccess` to the related route:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://a.com/apps/x [R=301,L]
```

So whenever I access `a.com/x` I get redirected to `a.com/apps/x`.